# Repl.it unhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, replit

I wanted to implement a rudimentary leaderboard to my game on Repl.it, so I created a node.js backend. This is what I have on the backend:

```
const express = require('express');
const Client = require('@replit/database');
const db = new Client();

const cors = require('cors');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const server = express();
server.use(cors());
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

server.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Online');
});

server.post('/leaderboard', async (req, res) => {
  const m = await db.get('leaderboard');
  m.push({
    score: parseInt(req.body.score, 10),
    time: new Date()
  });
  m.sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score);
  await db.set('leaderboard', m);
    
  res.send(req.body);
});

server.get('/leaderboard', async (req, res) => {
  const leaderboard = await db.get('leaderboard');
  res.json(leaderboard);
});

server.listen(3000);
```

But whenever I try to POST,  I get the following error:

> (node:344) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null

> (node:344) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)

> (node:344) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

And if I try to GET, `res` returns `null` - probably since I'm not pushing anything when doing POST.

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Comment: btw your code was a pleasure to read. it is well-organized and made it easy to debug. i wish more questions would take this level of care <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to handle the promise rejection?**

You're getting the UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning because you have nothing to catch the errors happening in your asynchronous routes. See the express [error handling](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) guide. You need to attach some kind of error handler -

```js
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(...)

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
})

app.post(...)

app.get(...)

...
```

Calls to `next()` and `next(err)` indicate that the current handler is complete and in what state. `next(err)` will skip all remaining handlers in the chain except for those that are set up to handle errors...

**Why is the promise rejected?**

The error is happening because `m` is `null` and `null` does not have a `.push` method. Calling `null.push(...)` throws an error which causes the promise to be rejected with this error.

**Why does `m` have a `null` value?**

I don't know the repl.it API, but presumably there is no value for `db.get('leaderboard')` and that is why `m` is getting a `null` response. You could try fixing it like this

```js
server.get('/leaderboard', async (req, res) => {
  const leaderboard = (await db.get('leaderboard')) || [] // <-
  res.json(leaderboard);
});

server.post('/leaderboard', async (req, res) => {
  const m = (await db.get('leaderboard')) || [] // <-
  // ...
});
```

Adding `... || []` to the result says if the response of `db.get` is falsey (`null` is falsey), use the empty array, `[]`, instead.

**replit/database**

```js
set(key: string, value: any): promise<void>
get(key: string): promise<any | null>
get(key: string, {raw: true}): promise<string | null>
```

[set](https://github.com/replit/database-node/blob/master/index.js#L55) automatically encodes the value using `JSON.stringify`.

[get](https://github.com/replit/database-node/blob/master/index.js#L28) is designed to retrieve JSON strings and automatically decode them. If no string is found, a `null` value returned, which is what your were experiencing.

Note, you can use `db.get(someKey, {raw: true})` to get the raw string back, skipping the `JSON.parse` step.